# Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_create_instance()

Tags: 8, entities

I'm helping to convert a Drupal 7 module across to Drupal 8 and getting an error on the install.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_create_instance()

I've seen in the Drupal 7 database that a table is created for *field_first_name* as *field_data_field_first_name*. Does this still happen in Drupal 8?

I resolved the fact that `field_info_field()` and `field_info_instance()` are now deprecated in Drupal 8 and have updated accordingly with `\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMap()` and `FieldConfig::loadByName()` respectively, but I can't find anything to suggest what to use instead of `field_create_instance()`; can someone suggest how I get around this?

My code is this.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 *
 * Adds custom fields used by module.
 */
function indicia_api_install() {
  $fields = array(
    'field_indicia_user_id' => (object) array(
      'type' => 'number_integer',
      'title' => 'User ID for this key on the warehouse',
      'name' => 'field_indicia_user_id',
    ),
  );

  foreach ($fields as $fielddef) {
    if (!\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMap($fielddef->name)) {
      \Drupal::logger('ima', 'Adding field: ' . $fielddef->name);
      $field = array(
        'field_name' => $fielddef->name,
        'type' => $fielddef->type,
      );
      if (isset($fielddef->required)) {
        $field['settings'] = array('required' => TRUE);
      }
      field_create_field($field);
    }
    else {
      \Drupal::logger('ima', 'Field already exists: ' . $fielddef->name);
    }
    if (!FieldConfig::loadByName('user', $fielddef->name, 'user')) {
      \Drupal::logger('ima', 'Adding instance: ' . $fielddef->name);
      $instance = array(
        'field_name' => $fielddef->name,
        'entity_type' => 'user',
        'label' => $fielddef->title,
        'bundle' => 'user',
        'required' => isset($fielddef->required) && $fielddef->required,
      );
      field_create_instance($instance);
    }
    else {
      \Drupal::logger('ima', 'Instance already exists: ' . $fielddef->name);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question, if anyone else comes across this - I worked out the solution in the end. Rather than implementing the hook_install() function I added the field information to the config/install/ folder which adds the necessary user fields instead.